# Queria saber porque eu consigo pegar os parâmetros dos verbos POST, PUT e DELETE no PHP apenas com JQuery, como faço isso JS puro?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript

**Queria saber como eu envio parâmetros dos métodos: POST, PUT, DELETE  assim como o JQuery faz**

Pra vocês entenderem melhor, eu quero apenas enviar um dado qualquer e pegar no PHP.
Se vocês observarem abaixo podem ver que na saída com JS puro ele retorna ***"null"***,
e eu quero retornar ***"{status: "success", datas: "[{"name":"marcos"}]"}"*** igual o JQuery faz, então a perguntar é: "Como eu faço pra retornar o mesmo valor assim como no JQuery?" *(Não precisa mexer no backend)*

```
// Without JQuery

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
const data: any = { name: 'marcos' }

xhr.responseType = 'json'
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(xhr.response) // output: null
  }
}
xhr.open(
  'post',
  'http://localhost/projetos/linguagens/PHP_api-rest/params/ajax/testAjax'
)

xhr.send(data)

// With JQuery

$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { name: 'marcos' },
  url: 'http://localhost/projetos/linguagens/PHP_api-rest/params/ajax/testAjax',
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response) // output: {status: "success", datas: "[{"name":"marcos"}]"}
  },
})
```

**Estou tentando pegar um parâmetro $_POST em PHP**

```
// Server
public function post() {
    return json_encode(['name' => $_POST['name']]);
}
```

Para ficar mais legível deixei uma imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0aCR.png

Answer (score 0):

É preciso serializar o seu objeto para enviá-lo fazendo `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))`.

A documentação pode ser consultada em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send.

PS: quando quiser saber exatamente o que/como o jQuery faz vc pode consultar o fonte deles diretamente no GitHub: https://github.com/jquery/jquery.